# Cannot find svg module typescript error in create-react-app

Tags: typescript, svg, create-react-app, react-typescript

In a create-react-app, I converted a jsx file that was working to a tsx file and this line:

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from "./logo.svg";
```

is throwing the typescript error:
Cannot find module './logo.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

In tsconfig.json I have:

```
{
  "include": ["src", "./src/**/*.ts", "./src/**/*.svg"]
}
```

It looks like node_modules/react-scripts/lib/react-app.d.ts already has:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  import * as React from 'react';

  export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<
    SVGSVGElement
  > & { title?: string }>;

  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

so I am not sure what the issue is.

The SVG has the following as the start of it:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100" width="100"><path d="M38.0
```

Answer (score 9):

I think it needs an explicit reference to the react-scripts library.

I have this file `src/react-app-env.d.ts` with this line:

```
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />
```

This file would have been normally created by Create React App.

Comment: Is this issue caused by manually migrating to TS, not using create-react-app with `--template typescript`?